# Orbeon Forms 4.3 not using MySQL

Tags: mysql, jboss7.x, orbeon

I have installed JBoss 7.1.1, Orbeon Forms 4.3 and Mysql 5.6. My goal is to use MySQL for Orbeon. I have setup and tested the MySQL connection successfully in JBoss but from what I can tell, Orbeon is still not using MySQL. I created the MySQL tables as outlined in the "Oracle, MySQL, and DB2 Persistence Layers" document but the are not being populated with data when I create and fill out forms. I assume, then, that it is still using the build in eXist database.

Here is an excerpt from the server.log. You can see JBoss connect to the MySQL datasource

```
13:53:36,250 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/comp/env/jdbc/mysql]
```

I configured Orbeon by uncommenting the resource-ref in web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DataSource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/db</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

and setting the resource-ref in the jboss-web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/db</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>java:/comp/env/jdbc/mysql</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
```

The documentation for 4.0 references a properties-local.xml file which I created in WEB-INF/config which contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*" value="mysql"/>
```

My orbeon.log file remains at zero bytes at all times. When creating and populating forms I still see references to the exist database in the server.log:

```
database instance 'exist' will have between 1 and 20 brokers
database instance 'exist' will be synchronized every 120,000 ms
database instance 'exist' will wait  120,000 ms during shutdown
database instance 'exist' is enabled for transactions : true
```

Another interesting thing I noticed is that Orbeon seems to be using a properties-prod.xml that I can't find in the WAR file

```
[org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.Orbeon$] (MSC service thread 1-1) Using properties file: oxf:/config/properties-prod.xml
```

No records are being added to the MySQL tables I created. I thought that the form definition and data tables would hold information pertaining to building and populating forms.

I have spent many hours on trying to get this working. Can anyone point me at what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `properties-local.xml` file is incorrect. There must be a `<properties>` root element, and `<property>` elements go beneath it. The easiest way to get started is to copy `properties-local.xml.template` first.

For further reference, the properties documentation is [here](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties). I clarified the fact that property files must have a root element.

Comment: Thanks you. That definitely helped point it to MySQL. Now to figure out the causes of the exceptions I'm seeing. I may have to post another question.